# Writing subquery for same table to access distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to find number of records that are exclusively not in retailer_id 27,28, 29. But this query isn't working in hive. Can you suggest where am I going wrong.

Tried Subquery on same table but this doesn't seem to work.

```
Select count(Distinct T.hhid) 
  from transactions 
 where hhid NOT IN (Select hhid 
                      from transactions 
                     where retailer_id IN (4,5,6,7,8,13,17,20,21,25,31) 
                       and transaction_date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-07-31'
                    ) as T 
 where T.retailer_id IN (27, 28, 29) 
   and transaction_date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-07-31'


ERROR : missing EOF at 'as' near ')'
```

If you could suggest something in spark-sql that will also work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusively not in"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want only those records which use transactions of retailer_id 27,28,29. There are hhid with transaction with both retailer_id in (27,28,29) & (4,5,6,7,8,13,17,20,21,25,31). I don't want those hhid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct T.hhid) 
FROM transactions T 
WHERE hhid NOT IN (
    Select hhid 
    from transactions 
    where retailer_id IN (4,5,6,7,8,13,17,20,21,25,31) 
    and transaction_date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-07-31'
) 
AND T.retailer_id IN (27, 28, 29) 
AND transaction_date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-07-31'
```

Comment: Where is the alias `T` defined in your query? Also, what is the purpose of the sub-query?

Comment: hhid NOT IN (...) and T.retailer_id IN (...)  things are may not same. Op must have his or her own logic to check that. I just corrected the Syntax issue in the query.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they miss an opportunity to educate and empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense in a number of ways:

- The `as T` at the end is in the wrong place. What specifically are you trying to make the alias `T` represent?
- Your two lists of `retailer_id` seem to be redundant. In the one case you are selecting records where `retailer_id` `IS NOT IN  (4,5,6,7,8,13,17,20,21,25,31)` and then you are adding a `WHERE` clause that states that `retailer_id IS IN`(27, 28, 29)`. Why both?

I think you might want to start over and determine what your select criteria is and go from there.

Comment: I want only those records which use transactions of retailer_id 27,28,29. There are hhid with transaction with both retailer_id in (27,28,29) & (4,5,6,7,8,13,17,20,21,25,31). I don't want those hhid.